# browserify cannot find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs, browserify, reactify

I have this bit of react code called `main.js`:

```
var React = require('react');

var Comment = React.createClass({
render: function(){
  return (
    <div className="comment">
      <h2 className="commentAuthor">
        {this.props.author}
      </h2>
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize:true})}} />
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

And I am trying to use browserify and reactify with it:

`browserify -t reactify main.js`

But I am getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react' from '/Users/jameslin/projects/reactjs/react-0.13.2'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Given that I have installed `react` and `reactify` npm modules by:

- `npm install -g react`
- `npm install -g reactify`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The moment I posted my question, and seems I found the answer, installed the module locally fixed it.

`npm install react`

But then I get another error:

`Error: EMFILE, open '/Users/jameslin/node_modules/react/package.json'`

UPDATE:

running `ulimit -n 10000` fixed the issue

Comment: But why? (morecharacterstopost)